# how i can accessing to user information in element

Tags: cakephp, authentication, element

i use cakephp and i want create login element .
this layout work as : 
1- when i should login , that element should show this code:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'legend' => __('Login', true),
    'username',
    'password'
));
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
```

2- when i logged and element should show my information such as username or email.
if i use view i can use `$this->Auth` but i can't use this way , there is another way for elements , thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get information of loggedin user from session in elements, like:

```
//check if user is logged in
if (!$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')) {
  //show your login form here
}
else {
  //the user is loggedin
  //get the loggedin users's information from session
  $username = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username');
  $email = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.email');
}
```

Did you mean something like that

Comment: I would argue that is not the right place to put that logic. You should read the logged in state in the controller, then simply pass the user data into the view, and then decided to show based on whether that is present.